# How to get the term description in a taxonomy term archive query?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, loop, taxonomy, query, terms

I'm creating a template for a custom taxonomy for my theme.

At the beginning of the page, **before the loop** that lists all the posts associated to a **term** of that taxonomy, I want to output the **description** for that term.

I have tried with

```
term_description()
```

but it doesn't work, no output...  get_the_terms and other functions I know are meant to work within a loop for individual posts (with post->ID)...

Anyone has a clue on how to achieve this? many thanks

Comment: Are you using echo or print to show the function's output?

Comment: oh had to echo it, that was simple to solve, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `term_description()` function returns the description rather than echoing or printing it.

To fix the issue, use:

```
echo term_description();
```